# Passing value from textbox to a different HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, textbox

So I have a homepage where the user is prompted to enter a username in a textbox. When the user clicks the button beneath the textbox that says 'FINISH SETTING UP PROFILE', it will take them to a new HTML page called createUser which contains several more textboxes, prompting the user to fill out a password, age, gender, etc.

The first of those textboxes in createUser will be a username box. I want the username the user entered from the homepage to save and display within the textbox shown in createUser. The user can still edit their username if they want to with this textbox, but I would like it so that if the user entered "Sarah" in the homepage, the username textbox on the new page will automatically be filled with the name "Sarah" when it loads so they don't have to fill it in again (but can still edit if they want).

I found a few similar questions online and ended up with the code below. It doesn't currently work, and was wondering if someone could help push me in the right direction?

homepage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input type="text" id="username" ><br><br>
</form>


<div id="createUser"><a href="createUser.html">FINISH SETTING UP PROFILE</a></div>

<script src="homepage.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

homepage.js

```
function onClickHandler(){
    location.href = 'createUser.html?name=' + document.getElementById('username').value;
}
```

createUser.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<h2>FINISH FILLING OUT INFO</h2>

<form>
    <input type="text" id="username" ><br><br>
</form>

<script src="createUser.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

createUser.js

```
function parseQueryString(){
    var queryDict = {}
    location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {
        queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]
    });

    return queryDict;
}

function onLoadHandler(){
    document.getElementById('username').value = parseQueryString().name;
}
```

Comment: Is the `onLoadHandler()` being called? I don't see it being called in the HTML or JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this on the homepage.js
It will listen when the user clicks the link and change the href before requesting the next page.

```
function onClickHandler(e){
    document.querySelector('a').href = "createUser.html?name=" + document.getElementById('username').value; 
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
}
```

Add this at the end of createUser.js so it will fill the input after the window has loaded

```
window.onload = onLoadHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are suggesting above sounds right by passing the username as a query param. I'd recommend using the URLSearchParams api as it will give a really nice developer experience

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

To the point where

```
function parseQueryString(){
var queryDict = {}
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {
    queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]
});

return queryDict;
}

function onLoadHandler(){
  document.getElementById('username').value = parseQueryString().name;
}
```

Can become, with input query string of createUser.html?name=

```
 function parseQueryString(){
    const queryParams = window.location.search;
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
    if(searchParams.has("name")){
      return searchParams.get("name");
    }
    
    return null
  }

    function onLoadHandler(){
     const userNameFromQueryString = parseQueryString();
     if(userNameFromQueryString){
     document.getElementById('username').value = userNameFromQueryString
     }
    }
```

Then in the body of the file you want this js to execute add

`<body onload="onLoadHandler()">`

Hope this is of some help